# Не отображается PDF файл в новом окне браузера

Tags: javascript, pdf

Вот собственно код:

```js
function pdf(){
  var widthImage = 400;
 var heightImage = 400;
 var newWin = open('','Печать','width='+ widthImage +',height='+ heightImage  + ',status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbar=0,resizable=yes');
 newWin.document.writeln('<html><head></head><body>pdf<hr><object><embed src=scr="www.bstu.ru/shared/attachments/82141" width="400" height="400" /></object></body></html>');
 newWin.document.close();
 newWin.focus();
 //newWin.print();
 //newWin.close();
}

function jpg(){
 var widthImage = 400;
 var heightImage = 400;
 var newWin = open('','Печать','width='+ widthImage +',height='+ heightImage  + ',status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbar=0,resizable=yes');
 newWin.document.writeln('<html><head></head><body>jpg<hr><img scr="www.dreempics.com/img/picture/Mar/25/9b1e838c79c65f22a6535a9a32a51387/mini_2.jpg"></body></html>');
 newWin.document.close();
 newWin.focus();
 //newWin.print();
 //newWin.close();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="pdf();">pdf</button>
<button onclick="jpg();">jpg</button>
```

Разметка работает нормально но файлы не отображаются. В чем причина?

---- Обновлено ------

```js
function pdf(){
  var widthImage = 400;
var heightImage = 400;
var newWin = open('','Печать','width='+ widthImage +',height='+ heightImage  + ',status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbar=0,resizable=yes');
newWin.document.writeln('<html><head></head><body>pdf<hr><object><embed src="http://www.bstu.ru/shared/attachments/82141" width="400" height="400" /></object></body></html>');
newWin.document.close();
newWin.focus();
//newWin.print();
//newWin.close();
}

function jpg(){
var widthImage = 400;
var heightImage = 400;
var newWin = open('','Печать','width='+ widthImage +',height='+ heightImage  + ',status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbar=0,resizable=yes');
newWin.document.writeln('<html><head></head><body>jpg<hr><img src="http://www.dreempics.com/img/picture/Mar/25/9b1e838c79c65f22a6535a9a32a51387/mini_2.jpg"></body></html>');
newWin.document.close();
newWin.focus();
//newWin.print();
//newWin.close();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="pdf();">pdf</button>
<button onclick="jpg();">jpg</button>
```

Теперь не отображается только PDF файл. В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 2):

ссылки неправильно указал. Если ты хочешь, чтобы они открывались нужно добавить http:// 
и еще атрибуты src неправильно написаны. в jpg() стоит scr вместо src. про pdf() я точно не знаю, но там ошибка такая же.

```js
function pdf(){
  var widthImage = 400;
 var heightImage = 400;
 var newWin = open('','Печать','width='+ widthImage +',height='+ heightImage  + ',status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbar=0,resizable=yes');
 newWin.document.writeln('<html><head></head><body>pdf<hr><object><embed src="http://www.bstu.ru/shared/attachments/82141" width="400" height="400" /></object></body></html>');
 newWin.document.close();
 newWin.focus();
 //newWin.print();
 //newWin.close();
}

function jpg(){
 var widthImage = 400;
 var heightImage = 400;
 var newWin = open('','Печать','width='+ widthImage +',height='+ heightImage  + ',status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbar=0,resizable=yes');
 newWin.document.writeln('<html><head></head><body>jpg<hr><img src="http://www.dreempics.com/img/picture/Mar/25/9b1e838c79c65f22a6535a9a32a51387/mini_2.jpg"></body></html>');
 newWin.document.close();
 newWin.focus();
 //newWin.print();
 //newWin.close();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="pdf();">pdf</button>
<button onclick="jpg();">jpg</button>
```

Comment: c src уже разобрался, теперь не ясно почему pdf не открывается

Answer (score 0):

Что бы открывался pdf файл в тег `embed` нужно добавить аргумент `type="application/pdf"`.